# Authorize.net xml get form token for redirect method

Tags: xml, authorize.net

I am puzzled, on Authorize.Net developer section for integration to BofA, is there a method to get the form token that I am overlooking so I can use the form redirect to authorize.net like I did with Payeezy worked (deprecated) and part of an ARB example from stackoverflow post.

```
post_url = "https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api"
```

versus

```
post_url = "https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment"
```

REFERENCE: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#gettingstarted-section-section-header

I found various examples of types of transaction calls, yet nothing  My test credential works, and the samples populated JSON and XML work yet I believed I could redirect to an authorize.net hosted form versus hosting their iframe on my secure page. I looked through the GitHub resources and nothing has led me to any series of Create Transaction Request or GetToken with just the Authentication credentials and Amount as suggested and then send over the extra User Fields collected and let Authorize.Net host and handle and finish the payment processing and receipt, instead of on my SSL hosted client.

suggested examples or links appreciated.

goal: to have a simple XML calling function to get a Form Token from Authorize.Net and then turn around and Submit via form redirect to authorize.net hosted ssl page instead of an ssl embedded iframe on my site.

Comment: Are you talking about OAUTH2 Token?  It looks like the link you provided doesn't use OAUTH2, but the login info can be used for OAUTH2.  See https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-merchant-details

Comment: Thanks jdweng - for the example for retrieve merchant details.

"the Requesting the Form Token"

What is the JSON/REQUEST command to get a form token, and then submit the form with user fields to an authorize hosted page on "their site"?


Integrate the form using a redirect, in which case the payment form fills the full browser window.

Displaying the Form --  Call the form by passing the form token that you received from the token element in the getHostedPaymentPageResponse API response.  You can integrate and display the Accept Hosted payment form on your site in three ways:

Comment: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept-hosted.html#AcceptHosted_JSONRequest

Comment: Do a google search for "msdn oauth2 authorize"  Use my link which uses OAUTH2.

Comment: Thank you jdweng - i figured it out. i solved the client side first, and then by luck that led me to the server side. here is what I learned and the Get Accept Payment Page was the server side..  

https://www.mountaincomputers.org/myBlog/myBlog.asp?mode=view&id=1803